# Exec and variable scope

Tags: python

Python 3.5.1

Could you have a look at the code and the picture.

This is some Django code, but the question relates to Python.

Well, I get the error:

```
Exception Value:    
name 'objects' is not defined
Exception Location:
/home/michael/workspace/pharchive/pharchive/general/templatetags/md_aux.py in get_aux_info, line 17
```

Line 17 is context = Context({"objects": objects}). In the picture it is visible.

I tried to add objects=[] a little above. But that didn't help. In this case objects was really empty. So, I commented it out.

Well, in the screenshot we can what we get if we stop at the breakpoint. We can see that objects var is really accessible in the context. And it contains something.

Anyway, I got stuck with variable scope.

I don't understand:
1. Why objects=[] didn't help me.
2. Why I get this error whereas objects is accessible.

Could you give me a kick here?

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_aux_info(master_document, aux_type):    
    md = MasterDocument.objects.get(pk=master_document)
    template = get_template("general/md_tags.html")

    #objects = []
    code = "objects = md." + aux_type +"s.all()"
    exec(code)
    context = Context({"objects": objects})
    return template.render(context)
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `exec`? Wouldn't `objects = getattr(md, aux_type + 's').all()` do the job?

Comment: I have managed to cope with exec myself. Well, I getattr have not been in my armory. Now it is. Thank you . If you form it as an answer, I would gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much easier approach than building and `exec`uting the code as a string would be to access the attribute using the built-in [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) function. This makes it clearer what's going on and side-steps your current scope issues entirely:

```
objects = getattr(md, aux_type + 's').all()
```

Python has extensive support for this kind of introspection; using `exec` (and `eval`) is usually a warning that you're approaching something in the wrong way.